# Store the word of a string in a file.txt into a variable AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a file.txt which is composed by some string each one is structured like this:

```
 word1 word2 word3
```

I would like to write a script which allows me to find the string which start with "word1" and get the content of "word2" and "word3" into two variables.

Comment: do shell script "var1=$(grep “string to search” file.txt|cut  -d " " -f 3);
var2=$(grep “string to search” file.txt|cut  -d " " -f 5)"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
set searchTerm to "foo"
set variable1 to ""
set variable2 to ""

set theText to paragraphs of (read (choose file))
repeat with aLine in theText

    set theWords to words of aLine
    if item 1 of theWords is searchTerm and ((count theWords) > 3) then
        set variable1 to item 2 of theWords
        set variable2 to item 3 of theWords
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```